# does two recursive calls work simultaneously or one after the other?

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion

so I was testing the recursive function , that is  , will the function at first recursion ,  let the recursion complete and then proceed or will it simply initialize the recursion and proceed on , that is will both the recursive calls print numbers simultaneously or first it will print `num` to 1 and then it will print `num` to 100 ;
anyway , my compiler is just outputing 32 infinitely when i give `num` as 23 ;

```
void print(int num){
   if(num == 1 || num == 100){
        return;
    }
    std::cout << num ;
    print(num-1);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    print(num+1);

    return;
}
```

Comment: `print(2)` after printing to the condole calls `print(1)`, which does nothing, and then call `print(3)` which prints and then calls `print(2)` again; at that point you're back to where you started (unless you've got a stackoverflow and the program crashes....)

Comment: What did you *expect* this to produce, and even more importantly, *why* ? You need to be able to answer those questions *before* you dive into what the behavior is as-observed, otherwise you're chasing your own tail with blinders on. To answer your question, however, concurrent execution will only happen if either any one of threading, async-exec, or omp is used, and none of those apply here, so no, there is no concurrent execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For recursion to work, like *mathematical induction*, there should be a clear direction of progress. Usually this means that `num` should either increase in every step of recursion, or decrease, but not both. This is not the case in your function, which alternates between increasing and decreasing.

Let us analyze what happens when you call `print(2)`. This will call both `print(1)` and `print(3)`. Clearly, `print(1)` exits immediately but `print(3)` will continue to recurse. You would like the `3` branch to continue to 4, 5, etc., but the recursion will (want to) split again into two directions: `print(2)` and `print(4)`, instead of just executing `print(4)`.

There is a sense of Déjà vu, as `print(2)` has been started previously. It again will call `print(1)` and `print(3)`.

Eventually, you will be printing 2 and 3 infinitely, or maybe your program will crash due to stack-overflow. The exact behavior (a crash or an infinite run) depends on whether or not the compiler is smart enough to figure out that this is an infinite recursion.

I'll repeat again, for a recursive function to work, its subsequent calls must follow the same direction through all the calls - either strictly increasing or decreasing.

In case there are multiple arguments, there should be some total-order relation which is followed through all calls. So that if `recursive(x1,y1,z1)` calls `recursive(x2,y2,z2)`, then `(x1,y1,z1) < (x2, y2, z2)` under this total order.

Another requirement, which you meet, is to have the termination condition on the path of progression.  If you understand mathematical induction, try to prove your algorithm using induction.

So, in your case you can fix this by recursing on two parameters simultaneously:

- One parameter will strictly increase.
- Another parameter will strictly decrease.

Try a hand-waving induction-like explanation before running the code. Step: does each parameter progress in one direction? Base: is it guaranteed to get to the stop condition? A formal proof is more complicated, but hand-waving explanation is usually enough to convince yourself of correctness - or find a flaw.

Answer (score 2):

That's because when you reach `num == 2`, what happens is that you call `print(1)` and stop the recursion, so you go newline and then call `print(3)` which prints 32 and then stop the recursion but then it will call again `print(3)` at some point.

Any recursive algorithm must get nearer to the end of the recursion in the recursive case, this is not what happens because with `num` as an argument you end up calling `print(num-1)` and `print(num+1)` thus you go back further from the end, so recursion never ends.

Answer (score 0):

What you're basically doing here is flooding the stack with print() calls, that is your first call to the print function print(num-1) is going to get called recursively untill one of the stop conditions is met. The stopping condition is sometimes met but since you're doing +1 and -1, that is calling the function two times in the same context with no extra checks, it will create a ping pong of infinitely recursive loops, thus resulting in a stack overflow

What you're seeing as '2' and '3' are the last prints of the function calls before it gets to the infinitely recursive ping pong

Watch out, any input given that is not between 1 and 100 will make your function get called infinitely